# Efficient way to hide rows from table

Tags: jquery, html, css, telerik

I have an html table with 1000 rows. I want to sort/search those rows on the client. Data comes from a webservice.
Now, I was thinking about adding paging with 100 rows per page, but the client side performance is bad. (I was thinking about doing something like: `display:none;` for hidden rows.

Now, I've started looking around for some implementations of this approach, and found out that datatables allow you to do sorting/search client side without adding those rows to the dom first.  http://datatables.net/   I looked at the generated dom in developers console and still cannot figure out how they hide rows. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes you should use datatable plugin in your code. These are the most efficient way to paginate your table. Datatable provides searching or paging with ajax result also.

Comment: @ManishJangir, I'm asking how datatables plugin works on the backend. I cannot use the plugin, I just need to know how it can be implemented.

Comment: Why not use the plugin?  No sense in recreating their work for the exact same usecase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I looked at the generated dom in developers console and still cannot figure out how they hide rows. Any ideas?

The JS code reads the table into javascript variables, specifically into a variable oSettings.aoData.

From there, they only actually load the table elements that need to be seen, so they are not actually hiding and unhiding rows (i.e. with dispaly:none) - the table rows actually get removed from the DOM, stored as javascript objects, and loaded into or removed from the DOM as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Things exist even if they're not visible in the DOM.

From looking through their code it seems that they store it in a member variable for the DataTable instance. There they are free to manipulate the data without using the DOM, which probably speeds things up as well.